# Issue in reading data from hbase inserted through hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-zookeeper

I have created one hbase-hive table. In which i insert the data through hive.

```
CREATE TABLE hivetest(cookie string, timespent string, pageviews string, visit string, logdate string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "m:timespent, m:pageviews, m:visit, m:logdate")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbasetest");
```

Data is inserted properly. I can access the same data using the hbase shell. But, I have created one hbase client which returns null pointed exception while accessing the same data.

Now the catch is if i create one dummy hbase table and put some data through hbase shell **NOT  THROUGH HIVE** and try to fetch this data from hbase client. It doesn't give the error and return the data. 
Also, same thing happen if i try to put the data in some row of **hbasetest** table through hbase client and then try to fetch the same row. Now this time it gives me the data.

**So, my question is what is the difference in writing the data through hive and hbase shell?**

**Hbase Client:**

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
   Map variables = System.getenv();
   conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","192.168.0.92");
   HTable table;
   byte family[];
   byte qualifier[];           
   table = new HTable(conf, "hivetest");
   family = Bytes.toBytes("m");
   qualifier = Bytes.toBytes("logdate");             
   Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("cookie_value"));    
   Result r = table.get(get);         
   byte  valueObj[] = r.getValue(family, qualifier);     
   byte  keyObj[] = r.getRow();
   String key = new String(keyObj);  
   String value = new String(valueObj);   /* line where exception occur */
   System.out.println((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(key))).append(" = ").append(value).toString());
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hbase.test.HbaseExample.main(HbaseExample.java:51)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using hive version 0.9.0 ?
If it's so, that version has a bug. **SerDe of HBaseStorageHandler doesn't ignore white space between comma and column family**. This makes  that names of column families stored are different that you are expecting.

Line 51 in HbaseExample class is that?

```
 byte  valueObj[] = r.getValue(family, qualifier);
```

Try taking off white spaces between comma symbols and column family in SERDEPROPERTIES mapping.

see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3243